# how to access struts2 treenode value in action class when it is clicked

Tags: struts2

I am using struts2 in my project .
 I  used DOJO jar  for Treenode

but i don't know how to get

Treenode id/label in action class when it is clicked

Follow is  my "tree.jsp"  page  when i click on "java in action" treenode(leaf node)
i want this name is to be send immeditaly to action class.

```
<%@taglib  prefix="s"  uri="/struts-tags"%>

<%@ taglib prefix="sx" uri="/struts-dojo-tags"%>

<html>

<head>
   <sx:head/>
   <meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=UTF-8">
   <title>Example Tree Tag</title>
</head>
<body>
   <h1>Example tree & treenode Tag</h1>
   <div>
      <sx:tree id="books" label="Books" title="test" > 
         <sx:treenode label="Programing books" title="test">
         <sx:treenode label="Java" title="test">
         <sx:treenode id="Thread-Books" label="Core-Java" >
         <sx:treenode id="Thread-Books" label="Java in Action" />
         <sx:treenode id="Thread-Books" label="Core-Java Essentials" />
         <sx:treenode id="Thread-Books" label="Head first Java" />
         <sx:treenode id="Thread-Books" label="Multi-threading" />
         <sx:treenode id="Thread-Books" label="Networking" />
         </sx:treenode>
      </sx:tree>
```

Comment: provide some code what you have done and where you are facing the issue,else its hard to help for anyone

Comment: i believe you missed to add the code :)

Answer (score 2):

You need add following code

```
<script language="JavaScript" type="text/javascript">
dojo.event.topic.subscribe("treeSelected", function treeNodeSelected(node) {
    alert(node);
    dojo.io.bind({
        url: "<s:url value='../roseindia/objectsList2.action'/>?categoryId="+node.node.title,
        load: function(type, data, evt) {
            var divDisplay = dojo.byId("displayIt");
            divDisplay.innerHTML=data;
        },
        mimeType: "text/html"
    });
});
```

sx:treenode label passed as node.node.title